# python locale for gtk does not work on windows

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have python 2.7 and pygtk. I am trying to set locale language for gtk in my application but no luck. My windows is in slovak language and I would like to have button labels in my app in english. How to solve it?

I tried this but no luck (all labels are still in slovak):

```
import os
os.environ['LANGUAGE'] = 'en_US'  #tried en_UK as well
os.environ['LANG'] = 'en_US'
os.putenv('en_US', 'LANG')
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'English_United Kingdom.1252' )
```

but when I make cmd file this works:

```
    set LANG=en_US
    something.exe
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is becoming a common question these days and should probably become a PyGTK FAQ.
See for example this PyGTK [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=574520)

In short, there's a whole lot of details you're missing. For example:

1) Starting with Python 2.4, on Windows, assigning values to os.environ only
changes the copy of the environment variables Python manages and no longer has
any effect on the copy maintained by the C library (msvcr90 for Python, msvcrt
for the various GTK+ related dll's).

2) Once you take care of the above you also need to take special care of
configuring libintl. That means you'll need to bindtextdomain() and
bind_textdomain_codeset() both intl.dll and Python's gettext module.

There's probably more that I don't remember right now, but you could take a
look at my [elib.intl](https://github.com/dieterv/elib.intl/blob/master/lib/elib/intl/__init__.py) module written specifically for what you're trying to
do (and more). When you have it working, you can simply set the LANGUAGE
environment variable to C to have the default American English.

You can do that
either from a .bat or .cmd file or by using os.environ['LANGUAGE'] = 'C' befory
you import elib.intl.

Comment: hello Dieter, thank you for great explanation and your fantastic module! I have implemented your module and now translations works correctly but unfortunately I have problem when I use py2exe. After clicking on exe file it ends with error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sss.py", line 1539, in <module>
  File "sss.py", line 512, in __init__
  File "elib\__init__.pyc", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources --- How can I solve this problem with pkg_resources ? thank you in advance

Comment: Ah yes, the py2exe problem... Py2exe does not seem to support 
namespaced packages and thus has trouble with pkg_resources.

One option is to just take the elib/intl/__init__.py file and
save it locally inside your project as intl.py (making sure you
change your imports to "import intl" and then use it as follows:
"intl.install()" or "intl.install_module()".