# Change gtk.BUTTONS_YES_NO in different language

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm building a multi lingual application in python, but when I use the gtk.BUTTONS_YES_NO, it always show only "YES" or "NO", how can I set the text to be, YES, SIM, SI or any other string?

```
dialog = gtk.MessageDialog(self, gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, gtk.MESSAGE_QUESTION, gtk.BUTTONS_YES_NO, txt_sendingToDevice)
dialog.format_secondary_text(txt_confirmSendToDevice)
response = dialog.run()
dialog.destroy()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you only use stock buttons and you have installed support for the locale that you want to display, under Linux you can run this:

```
import gtk
dialog = gtk.MessageDialog(None, gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, 
        gtk.MESSAGE_QUESTION, gtk.BUTTONS_YES_NO, "Hello world")
response = dialog.run()
dialog.destroy()
```

Starting with:

```
LC_ALL='sv_SE.utf8' python test.py
```

should display, "Nej" and "Ja" buttons (Swedish). And:

```
LC_ALL='en_US.utf8' python test.py
```

should display, "No" and "Yes" buttons.

You can also set this explicit in code:

```
import gtk
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'sv_SE.utf8')
dialog = gtk.MessageDialog(None, gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, 
        gtk.MESSAGE_QUESTION, gtk.BUTTONS_YES_NO, "Hello world")
response = dialog.run()
dialog.destroy()
```

### Prerequisites

Install the appropriate language pack, e.g. in this case Swedish (sv):

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-sv language-pack-gnome-sv
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to have the appropriate gnome translation pack installed also. For instance language-pack-gnome-sv to get Swedish.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, I'm NOT on linux, I'm on windows XP :)

Comment: Ok, then perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013500/python-locale-for-gtk-does-not-work-on-windows) may be of further help to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up doing my own widget, so I can put the text I want! :)

Comment: Your welcome @DanielSpillereAndrade! Also worth mentioning: [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/docs/) may be helpful if you are planning more advanced internationalization support.

Comment: It worked like charm. The confusing part for me was that using glade to set the layout you did not need the language pack to translate any label except the stock-buttons. I installed the right language pack and voia it worked.